# How to Display locking end time in asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a mechanism that will increase the lockout ending time based on how many time the user have entered a wrong password

```
case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
{
    if (failedAttempt > 0)
    {
        user.LockoutEnabled = true;
        user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5* failedAttempt);
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    return View("Lockout");
}
```

I would like to display that for the user in the lockout view :

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo   
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "locked";
}

<hgroup>
    <h1 class="text-danger">Verrouillé.</h1>
    <h2 class="text-danger">Ce compte a été verrouillé, veuillez réessayer./h2>
</hgroup>
```

how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow your scenario that when a user is not valid it only decresases your Invalid Attempts. It doesnt actually suspend the user unless they enter the login credentials correctly.

Really your sudo logic should go:

- Validate Credentials
- Credentials Valid
- Check account status, is suspended then deny access
- Reset the attempts back to 5
- Allow the user into the application
- Credentials invalid
- Decrease the attempts by one
- Set the account to suspended if required

Alot of this logic can really be bound into one or two methods. Also in your DecreaseAttempts() method you have two SQL Commands where the sql command cmd is never executed

Here is an example of doing it in one method returning an enum of a status. Now this is a very basic example but only requires one method to execute your full authorization methods. I have commented teh code.

```
public partial class UserManager 
{

    const int MaxAttempts = 5;

    public LoginStatus ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("username");

        //set the password to empty if it is null
        password = password ?? "";

        //create the connection
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
        {
            //assign some local variables
            int attemptsLeft = MaxAttempts;
            string currentStatus = "Active";
            string userPassword = null;

            //get the information for the user, only query by username so we have all the data. We will match the password later on
            string query = "SELECT TOP(1) [Username], [Password], [AttemptsLeft], [CurrentStatus] FROM [Information] WHERE Username = @username";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //no rows.. Invalid username
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                        return LoginStatus.InvalidCredentials;
                    }

                    //read the first row (hence the break)
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        attemptsLeft = (int)reader["AttemptsLeft"];
                        currentStatus = (string)reader["CurrentStatus"];
                        userPassword = (string)reader["Password"];
                        break;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }

            //if the account is suspended then dont even bother with password checking
            if (currentStatus.Equals("Suspended", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return LoginStatus.Suspended;
            }

            //invalid password lets handle the invalid credentials logic
            if (!password.Equals(userPassword))
            {
                attemptsLeft -= 1;

                //decrease the attempts, lets just stop at zero as we dont need negative attempts
                if(attemptsLeft >= 0)
                {
                    query = "UPDATE [Information] SET [AttemptsLeft] = @attemptsLeft WHERE Username = @username";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attemptsLeft", attemptsLeft);
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }

                //suspend the account when attempts less than or equal to zero
                if (attemptsLeft <= 0)
                {
                    query = "UPDATE [Information] SET [CurrentStatus] = @currentStatus WHERE Username = @username";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentStatus", "Suspended");
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    //exit method as login account suspended
                    return LoginStatus.Suspended;
                }

                //exit as invalid login credentials
                return LoginStatus.InvalidCredentials;
            }
            //if we are here lets quickly reset the login attempts back to 5, and account status to active as this is a valid login
            query = "UPDATE [Information] SET [AttemptsLeft] = @attemptsLeft, [CurrentStatus] = @currentStatus WHERE Username = @username";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attemptsLeft", MaxAttempts);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentStatus", "Active");
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            //if we got here then every thing is a match
            return LoginStatus.Authorized;
        }
    }

}

public enum LoginStatus
{
    Authorized,
    InvalidCredentials,
    Suspended
}
```

To use this can be as simple as below (note you have to change the view redirections)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Credential. No username sent.");
        return View();
    }

    var manager = new UserManager();

    var result = manager.ValidateUser(username, password);

    switch (result)
    {
        case LoginStatus.Authorized:
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");

        case LoginStatus.InvalidCredentials:
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Credentials. Username or password incorrect");
            break;

        case LoginStatus.Suspended:
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account Suspeneded");
            break;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Just for fun I rewrote this into a simple stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ValidateUser
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @userPassword nvarchar(50) = NULL
    DECLARE @maxAttempts int  = 5
    DECLARE @attemptsLeft int = 5
    DECLARE @currentStatus nvarchar(50)

    /*
        RETURN CODES:
        0 = Authorized
        1 = InvalidCredentials
        2 = Suspended
    */


    SELECT TOP(1) @userPassword = [UserName], @attemptsLeft = [AttemptsLeft], @currentStatus = [CurrentStatus] FROM [Information] WHERE UserName = @username

    IF @userPassword IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1 as [Result], @maxAttempts as [AttemptsRemaining]
            RETURN
        END

    --account suspended.. Return a suspended result
    If @currentStatus = 'Suspended'
        BEGIN
            SELECT 2 as [Result], 0 as [AttemptsRemaining]
            RETURN
        END

    --passwords dont match (note this is case insensitive on default collation)
    If @password IS NULL OR @password <> @userPassword
        BEGIN
            --decrease attempts
            SET @attemptsLeft = @attemptsLeft - 1

            --if the attempts left are greater than 0 then set the account active and decrease the attempts remaining
            IF @attemptsLeft > 0
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE [Information] SET [CurrentStatus] = 'Active', AttemptsLeft = @attemptsLeft WHERE UserName = @username
                    SELECT 1 as [Result], @attemptsLeft as [AttemptsRemaining]
                    RETURN
                END
            --else the attempts left are less than or equal to zero therefore they should be suspended and attempts left set to zero (dont want negative attempts)
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE [Information] SET [CurrentStatus] = 'Suspended', AttemptsLeft = 0 WHERE UserName = @username
                    SELECT 2 as [Result], 0 as [AttemptsRemaining]
                    RETURN
                END
        END
    --if we get here then all is good and we can just reset the account status and max attempts for the next login attempt
    UPDATE [Information] SET [CurrentStatus] = 'Active', AttemptsLeft = @maxAttempts WHERE UserName = @username
    SELECT 0 as [Result], @maxAttempts AS [AttemptsRemaining]

END
GO
```

Then calling this is very simple (note i have also changed the return type to a call that returns both the status and the attempts remaining.

Method

```
public LoginResult ValidateUserStoredProcedure(string username, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("username");

    //set the password to empty if it is null
    password = password ?? "";

    //create the connection
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
    {
        var result = new LoginResult
        {
            AttemptsRemaining = 5,
            Status = LoginStatus.InvalidCredentials
        };
        try
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("EXEC ValidateUser @username, @password", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Status = ((LoginStatus)(int)reader["Result"]);
                        result.AttemptsRemaining = (int)reader["AttemptsRemaining"];
                        break;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Close();

            Debug.WriteLine("Error on sql query:" + ex.Message);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Result Class

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public LoginStatus Status { get; set; }

    public int AttemptsRemaining { get; set; }
}

public enum LoginStatus : int
{
    Authorized = 0,
    InvalidCredentials = 1,
    Suspended = 2
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Credential. No username sent.");
        return View();
    }
    var manager = new UserManager();
    var result = manager.ValidateUserStoredProcedure(username, password);
    switch (result.Status)
    {
        case LoginStatus.Authorized:
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");

        case LoginStatus.InvalidCredentials:
            if (result.AttemptsRemaining < 5)
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Credentials. Username or password incorrect. Attempts remaining:" + result.AttemptsRemaining);
            else
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Credentials. Username or password incorrect.");
            break;

        case LoginStatus.Suspended:
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account Suspeneded");
            break;
    }
    return View();
}
```

How you optimize is up to you but this level of authorization is rather weak. It also shows you are storing your passwords as plain text. But that is another topic all together.

Comment: thank you ravikumar , I will test that tomorrow morning and let you know